# Kendo Real Time Chart

Tags: kendo-ui, datasource, real-time, linechart, kendo-dataviz

I want to add data to kendo linechart series but when I add data then kendo redraw chart with all series so it cause performance problem. Is there any way draw it one by one ? Or how can I make real time line chart with kendo ?
This is my code. It cause performance problem.
http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/api/benchmark.html How can do it like in this link?

```
BlueChart.options.series[0].data.push(bvalue);
BlueChart.redraw();
```

Comment: Could you provide a working sample in jsbin so we can see the issue?

Comment: You should be working with the dataSource of the chart. `$('#myChart').data('kendoChart').dataSource.data()`. Every time on insert any data into your chart via the `.data()` method, it will cause a redraw of the chart. If you are messing with multiple series, or points of data at one time it is then much more efficient to get a local reference and then append data. `BlueChart.dataSource.data($.merge(BlueChart.dataSource.data(), newDataPoints));` would be a good way to append points to a chart. You could then apply a filter or slice earlier points depending on your goals.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the chart animation.  That will help a lot.  Here is a complete list of perf tips for the DataViz suite...

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dataviz/performance-tips